# Auto analyze not running for all tables in Postgres 9.2 database

Tags: database, postgresql

I've noticed that a database I am tuning (postgres 9.2) is not running autoanalyze for many of the tables I am interested in, and I don't quite understand why. My understanding/expectations is that based on the current configuration, autoanalyze will run assuming the table grows or is modified by >= 10% of the rows. However, this is not the case based on the information I am seeing when querying the database.

Here's a set of results from running a query on pg_stat_all_tables on a database that's been running in prod for over a year (results truncated and real table names redacted)

```
┌────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────┬───────────────────┐
│       relname      │ last_autovacuum │ autovacuum_count │ last_autoanalyze │ autoanalyze_count │
├────────────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ a_large_table      │ ¤               │                0 │ ¤                │                 0 │
│ table_a            │ 2014-04-01      │                1 │ 2014-04-01       │                 1 │
│ table_b            │ 2014-04-01      │                1 │ 2014-04-01       │                 1 │
│ a_very_large_table │ ¤               │                0 │ ¤                │                 0 │
└────────────────────┴─────────────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

Note, table_a and table_b are frequently cleaned of old data, so it makes sense that these would have had an autovacuum/autoanalyze recently. However, I'd also expect the other large tables to have been at least analyzed recently as well.

For good measure, here's the postgresql.conf...

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# AUTOVACUUM PARAMETERS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

autovacuum = on

log_autovacuum_min_duration = 1000

autovacuum_max_workers = 3

autovacuum_naptime = 1min

autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 100

autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 100

autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.2

autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.1

autovacuum_freeze_max_age = 200000000

autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 20ms

autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = -1
```

Comment: Do you have open connections that are in  the `<idle> in transaction` state? (You can check that through the view `pg_stat_activity`)

Comment: Yes. What specifically am I looking for on that view?

Comment: Connections in state `<idle> in transaction` keep locks that prevent autovacuum from removing the dead rows (because they aren't dead, those transactions are still seeing them). You need make sure you end all transactions with a `commit`. You should only have connections in `<idle>` state. Those won't prevent autovacuum from doing its job

Comment: running the command multiple times shows that the database floats between 8-15 connections in that state. What would you recommend to do given this?

Comment: As I said: make sure the code does a commit (or rollback) or close the connection completely.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://rhaas.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/troubleshooting-stuck-vacuums.html

Comment: Are there any manual analyzes?  Is there anything in the server log about analyze being cancelled due to locks?

Answer (score 0):

It does look like the tables should be vacuum analyzed when 10% of of the tuples are changed. Based on the posed postgresql.conf setting,

```
autovacuum analyze threshold = 100 + 0.1 * table size before vacuum
```

Other things to check:

- Is autovacuum running? `ps -ef | grep vacuum`
- Make sure you're not checking on a standby or slave server

See slides from Gabrielle Roth's autovacuum talk at Scale:
https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/b/b5/Groth_scale12x_autovacuum.pdf